# Unable to view requests under (View all requests) in ISIM 6.0

Tags: tivoli-identity-manager

I have installed ISIM 6.0 with a fix pack 6.  After installing the FixPack i was able to view the request of any activity performed in ISIM, but now View All Request tab doesn't show list of requests however the transactions are going through fine.   Please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

That usually means that ISIM web app cannot read the requests from the database.

I would enable DEBUG_MAX level in enRoleLogging.properties 
file in order to see the exact request made to the database and try to perform the same SQL query manually. 
I believe the component needed is
logger.trace.com.ibm.itim.util.level
But you can try setting the level to DEBUG_MAX for all

Then check your trace.log file(s). The location depends on your installation, more details can be found here :https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/mobile/#!/SSRMWJ_6.0.0/com.ibm.isim.doc_6.0/trouble/cpt/cpt_ic_trouble_itimop_logs.htm

Also check the log files of your isim DB.

Hint: The only time I have come across this exact issue was after an upgrade where the tenant got changed from dc=com to DC=COM. It's a common misconception that the tenant is case-insensitive as we tend to associate this to the LDAP, but it affects SQL queries also (and those are case-sensitive).

Answer (score 0):

ilektrojohn's answer should help you but anyways I have faced this couple of times in earlier stage and hence posting it. Usually its a slight mistake, and we forget to update the `Time Interval` or `Request Type` fields. Set them to wider range like `this week` or `this month`. Also expand the `More search criteria` and remove any added filters that might be restricting the search results.